# Need AMPScript function to convert string to decimal

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, string, decimal

In an email I have a variable coming in that is in string format (it's a price). I need to multiply that by another number, which means I need to convert the string to a number in the `xx.xx` format.

Does anyone know of an AMPScript function that will do this? I can't find one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMPScript is loosely typed.  You may want to utilize the **AttributeValue()** function so you can detect empty values in either number.  Here's how I would do it:

```
%%[
var @price, @qty, @extPrice
/*
set @price = AttributeValue("price")
set @qty = AttributeValue("qty")
*/
set @price = "12.34"
set @qty = "3"

if empty(@price) or empty(@qty) then
  set @extPrice = "0.00"
else
  set @extPrice = multiply(@price,@qty)
endif

]%%
<br>extPrice: %%=formatNumber(@extPrice,D2)=%%
```

**Output**

```
extPrice: 37.02
```

Reference

- [**Empty()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/empty.htm)
- [**AttributeValue()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm)
- [**Multiply()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Multiply.htm)
- [**FormatNumber()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response! To clarify, the value I'll be receiving will be a number in the form of a string. I was understanding that Multiply will only work with an integer. Is there something in your code that I'm missing that will rectify this?

Comment: When I say loosely typed, I mean AMPScript pretty much treats everything like a string.  So if it looks like a string and isn't empty, then the Multiply() function should work.